# Add direction to sphere without adding force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a Brick Breaking game in unity5.

My code is:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts) 
    {
        if(contact.thisCollider == collider1)
        {
            float cp = contact.point.x - transform.position.x;

            contact.otherCollider.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(reflectionForce * cp, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically my paddle is adding force to the ball depending on the distance of contact point from center. More the distance, more will be force and direction on the ball.

The problem is that if ball keeps getting hit on one side of paddle then its speed will increase each time it hits the paddle and ultimately getting impossible to hit.

So, is there any way by which I can add direction to ball without increasing its force.

Comment: yes, you can directly change the balls velocity. However! consider instead using the difference in velocity between the paddle and ball to affect the force

Comment: But the velocity should remain same, only direction should change

Comment: What if you use the second param of `AddForce()`: `ForceMode.Impulse` or any other? Check http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

Comment: I don't think they will work as force will be added somewhere no matter what mode I choose. And what should be added is just direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that add const velocity after each collision.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts) 
{
    if(contact.thisCollider == collider1)
    {
        float cp = contact.point.x - transform.position.x;
        contact.otherCollider.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(reflectionForce * cp, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        float maxSpeed = 2.0f; //for example
        Vector3 vel = contact.otherCollider.attachRigidbody.velocity;
        contact.otherCollider.attachRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(vel,maxSpeed);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried you code but it was giving velocity on just x-axis, as a result ball will move parallel to paddle. I gave it velocity on y-axis also, the same velocity the ball was carrying on the axis. 

Code:


    contact.otherCollider.attachedRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(reflectionForce * cp, contact.otherCollider.attachedRigidbody.velocity.y, 0.0f);

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do after collision?

Comment: I want that my ball should be moving at same speed but its direction should change based on distance from center of paddle.

Comment: Okay, After adding force you must clamp velocity's vector magnitude. The magnitude of velocity represents your rigidbody speed. I updated the answer you can see.

Comment: Thanks.
The answer worked, direction is variable but speed is constant. I also figured something that will keep the speed constant but it will also keep direction constant.
Code:


    float cp = contact.point.x - transform.position.x;
    float point = 0;
    if(cp > 0)
     point = 1f;
    else if(cp < 0)
     point = -1f;

    contact.otherCollider.attachedRigidbody.velocity =     new Vector3(reflectionForce * point,     contact.otherCollider.attachedRigidbody.velocity.y, 0.0f);

But your answer is the one I am looking for. I will mark it as answer. Thanks again